# How do I paint the steel crossbeam on a colorbond fence?

Tags: paint, fence, steel

I have a colorbond fence.

If you don't have colorbond in your area, it's painted steel panelling that can be used for fences or roofs. My fence looks like this:

[image: Colorbond]

But what you can't see is the back - there is an **unpainted steel crossbeam**.

I'm thinking about painting the crossbeam. Is there any particular preparation I should undertake with the steel?

I've heard I should sand it. And I should use a spray rather than brush... Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Your title says *stainless* steel. Is it stainless? How do you know?

Comment: @bib I assume it's stainless because it's outside. I don't know how to tell visually if it's stainless or not. Does it matter?

Comment: If it is stainless, it will not corrode and does not need to be painted. If there is any rust, it is not stainless.

Comment: @bib It's brand new so it has no rust right now, but I would rather paint it now than risk rust later on. Also, from what I've read, stainless doesn't mean it won't rust, but it will be less prone to rust.

Comment: I've updated the title, someone edited it to say stainless steel and I don't know if it's stainless or carbon steel.

Comment: It depends on the grade of stainless, and yes, many do rust slowly.

Comment: A good clue to whether it is stainless is if a magnet will stick to it. Most varieties of stainless that are used will not attract a magnet. (This is not true of all of them, but a good identifier for the common ones in use.) If a magnet does stick, then it is PROBABLY galvanized. This is a common material in fencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As suggested, use sand paper or steel brush to clear any rusty bit
2. Apply some(not too much) rust  remover / preventer - let it dry naturally (30minutes - 2hours?)
3. Paint with steel primer (usually grey)
4. Following the drying time guidelines of the primer apply your top coat of enamel or whatever you want.

Do not flood the steel with rust preventer. Let it dry and wash your hands properly. If the rust remover makes white bulges just remove it with a another tool. Do not touch with your hands to avoid a) acid burn, b) oil residue on steel

We use to do that in South Africa on all gate installations because summers were extremly dry and some winters could be torrential with flash flooding. This method lasts years and years.
(It is a method borrowed from the automotive industry - in its simplistic form)

Good luck

Comment: If it's not rusted can I skip the rust remover/sanding?

Comment: Yea sure. Just clean it with some spirits to remove any oily bits and do it. (But even if its not rusted - the rust remover (which is a diluted acid) acts as an inhibitor even after you painted over it because it bonds with the steel - So it prevents/helps stop rust bubbles form appearing for the years to come)

Answer (score 1):

I'll also recommend the same things that you have already indicated. Do sand the steel before painting it. If it has any rust or scale on it this must be removed by vigorous wire brushing till all the rust is gone. Spray painting is really the best way to paint steel so you must consider appropriate masking of adjacent areas so over spray does not get on other parts of the fence or driveway.

The best paint for this job will be an enamel paint specifically designed for the job of painting on metal. For a relatively small job, like this one seems to be, I would simply recommend that you use the spray can type that you can purchase at the home store or hardware store. Do use multiple light coats of paint to get a nice finish without problems with the paint running or dripping. The only drawback with spray cans is the limited range of colors available.

One last thing you may want to consider is the possibility to temporarily remove the steel cross beam from the gate and paint it separately so that you can get it painted from all sides. Then re-install it and go back and touch up the fasteners with a spritz of the spray paint.

Comment: If I use spray paint, do I need to use a primer?

Comment: Primer is always advised- as it helps lock/seal the steal and the final coat sticks to the primer better.You can get primer in spray pain- try and use the same companies spray paints

Comment: I agree. Use a good quality primer for a long lasting outdoor paint job.